# Why do i not get an alert when an error is thrown with dispatch?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm fairly new to react native and am trying to make up my first rn/expo app, however i faced an issue which im stuck on.

I was using fetch api to make calls onto firebase auth and db but i had to port over to firebase sdk (js/web) as i needed to use the storage firebase provides for images. I converted everything and it works well except the error handling part.

Here below i've my **AuthScreen.js** where i execute a function to either login or sign up a user,

```
const [error, setError] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Entered useEffect');
    if (error) {
      Alert.alert('Error Occured', error, [{ text: 'Close' }]);
    }
  }, [error]);

  const authHandler = async () => {
    let action;

    if (isLogin) {
      action = authActions.login(email, password);
    } else {
      action = authActions.signup(email, password, name);
    }
    setError(null);
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      await dispatch(action);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error', err);
      setError(err.message);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

<Button
  size='small'
  style={styles.button}
  status='basic'
  onPress={authHandler}
  icon={isLoading ? () => <ActivityIndicator /> : null}
>
   {isLoading ? null : 'PROCEED'}
</Button>
```

This is the action inside my redux store,

```
export const login = (email, pw) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
      .then(() => {
        const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref('/users/' + userId)
          .once('value')
          .then(snapshot => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            console.log('data', data);
            dispatch({ type: REMOVE_USER });
            dispatch({ type: GET_USER, user: data.name });
          })
          .catch(err => console.log('err.message', err.message));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        let message = 'An error has occured!';

        if (err.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
          message = 'Invalid email address!';
        } else if (err.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
          message = 'No account with such credentials!';
        } else if (err.code === 'auth/wrong-password') {
          message = 'Incorrect password! Try again.';
        }

        throw new Error(message);
      });
  };
};
```

When i try to re-enact an error, i just get a pop up error like this,

[image: Error]

It should've been an alert. I can't figure this out..

Comment: You're throwing an `Error`. That's probably going to take precedent over any other error handling logic you add.

Comment: Previously when i use the Fetch API to perform such operations, i threw errors the same way i did above. It was working fine. That's odd..

Comment: @BrianThompson i found the solution. I didn't add await in the async dispatch in my action function, Login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

Adding an **await** would've solved the issue. Any async dispatch would've required an **await**.

```
export const login = (email, pw) => {
return async dispatch => {
    await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
      .then(() => {
        const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref('/users/' + userId)
          .once('value')
          .then(snapshot => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            dispatch({ type: REMOVE_USER });
            dispatch({ type: GET_USER, user: data.name });
          })
          .catch(err => console.log('err.message', err.message));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        let message = 'An error has occured!';

    if (err.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
      message = 'Invalid email address!';
    } else if (err.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
      message = 'No account with such credentials!';
    } else if (err.code === 'auth/wrong-password') {
      message = 'Incorrect password! Try again.';
    }

    throw new Error(message);
  });
  };
};
```